# Transactions Not Starting using Spring and JPA in Tomcat

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, spring-transactions

I'm attempting to use JPA with Spring inside tomcat and having problems where transactions are not being started as expected.

I'm using Hibernate 3.6.9.Final, Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE and running in Tomcat 6.0.30.

I have a separate data access jar that contain my entities and data access objects. This jar contains a META-INF/persistence.xml file with the following content.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="osPU">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

As you can see it is very simple and really just a marker for JPA to know that this is jar contains JPA entities.

The entities are being found OK based on the following configuration in my spring beans file.

```
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="jpaProperties"> 
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${database.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${database.show.sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" >
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

I've marked my DAO with

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY)
```

since I want to make sure that all callers to the DAO's methods create a transaction properly.

I've added

```
@Transactional
```

to all methods where the DAOs are called from.

This results in an exception.

```
org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory'
```

If I remove the propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY from the DAO @Transactional annotation I get an error when the entityManager attempts to flush the changes.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**EDIT** I'm using Generics at all levels in the stack. Controller, Services and DAOs. Not sure if this is causing a problem with Spring being able to intercept the method invocations and wrap them in transactions.

**More Detail** Here is the controller code:

```
public abstract class AbstractEavDefinitionController<DTO> implements EAVDefinitionOperations<DTO> {

    private EavDefinitionService<DTO> eavDefinitionService;

    private Validator<DTO> validator;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ServiceResult<Long> save(@RequestBody DTO dto) {
        ValidationResult<DTO> validationResult = validator.validate(dto);

        if (validationResult.isValid()) {
            Long result = eavDefinitionService.save(dto);
            return new SimpleServiceResult<Long>(result);
        }

        return new SimpleServiceResult<Long>(validationResult);
    }
}
```

Both the validator and the service use DAOs that must have a transaction active. The validator call works as expected and I can see it making the DB call. The call to the service throws

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

What I don't understand is how one call to the DAO succeeds but the next fails. Is there a limit to the number of transactions that can be opened within a controller call when using Transactional?

Comment: ARe annotated methods called from another bean so calls can go through its proxy?

Comment: All calls, from the controller to the DAO, pass through spring managed beans. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Nope, important is how transactional controller methods are called. Transaction you want will start only if controller method call goes through a proxy.

Comment: By default the <tx:annotation-driven /> uses a proxy so I think that is the case. If not, then how do I tell?

Comment: Try `<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>` to begin with. If it resolves your problem it means you were bypassing proxy when making calls to transactional methods.

Comment: @mrembisz Got an exception because I'm using parameterized types. CGLib doesn't like them. I'm using Generics at almost all levels in the stack. DAO, Controller and services.

Comment: I guess you need to make sure jdk proxies will work with your controller. All methods marked as `@Transactional` come from an interface?

Comment: I'm fairly certain they are, otherwise how is the mandatory transaction intercepting the call to my DAO and throwing the exception.

Comment: The fact calls to dao are intercepted means daos are properly proxied. But what seems to be missing here is intercepting controller methods and opening transactions for them. You can post controller code to make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

As I guess, the DAO caller are not based on interface called by another spring-based component (@Controller ?, JAX-RS resources?, simple class bean,..)
So this class, even if it manages nicely @Autowired field, the @Transactional operations calls are not intercepted by Spring.
Configuration to solve your issue (assuming your are using LTW in your context) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <context:load-time-weaver />
    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean name="loadTimeWeaver" class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.mypackage" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="jpaProperties"> 
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${database.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${database.show.sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Sorry, I've been slow getting back to this. I don't think I can use proxy-target-class="true" since CGLIB complains about generic types.

Comment: About generic types ? Are you using cglib 2.2.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

James, the approach I took in the past was as follows.
Very basic persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="audit">
<!-- dont need props here as configured in Spring -->

<properties>

</properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

And then my spring context was wired up as follows (left out the datasource definition):

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config/>


<bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="${db.dialect}"/>
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
</bean>


<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="audit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter"/>
<property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        </props>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>


<bean id="auditDAO" class="com.gridfreak.core.audit.persistence.JPAAuditDAO"/>
```

And in my actual dao class, just inject the persistence context and mark methods transactional:

```
public class JPAAuditDAO implements AuditDAO {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="audit")
private EntityManager entityManager = null;


@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public List<VarAudit> findByPiid(long piid) {
        //...
    }

    //....
}
```

This was a trivial example, and wasn't delegating responsibility for transaction origination to a containing service.  Did you try marking the transactions as REQUIRED rather than mandatory and see if they are created then, in which case perhaps it's an issue with the transactional annotations of the service bean itself not being picked up?

Adam